# Failed to set the value property on HTMLInputElement: This input element accepts a filename,which may only be programmatically set to the empty string

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

when i try to upload image i got the error message which is already in question title:

this is my template

```
<input type="file" formControlName="avatar" accept=".jpg, .jpeg .svg"
   #fileInput (change)="uploadImage($event)" />

<div class="avatar-preview">
  <ng-template #selectedImage>
    <div style.backgroundImage="{{'url('+ imageUrl +')'}}"></div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
<button (click)="fileInput.click()"></button>
```

and this is my component ts

```
@ViewChild('fileInput') el: ElementRef;
imageUrl: string = "";

this.profileForm = new FormGroup({
  avatar: new FormControl(null)
});

public uploadImage(event) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.imageUrl = reader.result as string;
        this.profileForm.patchValue({
          avatar: reader.result
        });
      }
    }
    this.cd.markForCheck(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular doesn't contain a `ControlValueAccessor` for a file input. This means that it is using the `DefaultValueAccessor` which as defined in your FormControl tries to write the value of `avatar` to the control. This is not allowed for a FileInputControl.

Either you should implement one and then you could remove your `uploadImage` function as that would be moved to the `ControlValueAccessor`.

or remove `formControlName="avatar"` and don't use reactive forms as you are handeling the events yourself anyway.

example (not tested, you might have to make it into a component or change the selector as this could conflict with the `DefaultValueAccessor` selector):

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input[type=file][formControlName]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: FileUploadAccessor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class FileUploadAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
  private onChange: Function;

  @HostListener('change', ['$event.target.files']) emitFiles( event: FileList ) {
    const file = event && event.item(0);
    this.onChange(file);
  }

  constructor( private host: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement> ) {
  }

  writeValue( value: null ) {
    // clear file input
    this.host.nativeElement.value = '';
  }

  registerOnChange( fn: Function ) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched( fn: Function ) {
  }

}
```

optionally you could add your current processing to this directive aswell (instead of calling `this.onChange(file);`).

```
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = () => {
  this.onChange(reader.result as string);
}
```